# How to insert HTMLCollection into the page?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

In the following example, a HTMLCollection is created from a string containing HTML.

Is it possible to eventually add the HTML collection into another element, without having to add an additional surrounding div or template element?

```js
const stringHTML = `
 <div>
   <h1>This is a div</h1>
   <div>
    <p>inner div</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h2>Another div</h2>
  </div>
`;


/**
 * @param html {String} Representing a single HTML element
 * @return {HTMLCollection} The newly created element
 */
const stringToHTMLCollection = function(html) {
  /** @type {HTMLElement} */
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  html = html.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
  template.innerHTML = html;
  return template.content.children;
}

console.log(stringToHTMLCollection(stringHTML));

// This works.
Object.entries(stringToHTMLCollection(stringHTML)).forEach(([key, element])  => {
      result.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', element);
    });
    
// However isn't there a more elegant way using something similar to insertAdjecentHTML?
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: *Is it possible to eventually add the HTML collection into another element, without having to add an additional surrounding div or template element?* << This seems like it should be pretty easy for you to just try on your own and get your answer.

Comment: The [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) expects the second argument to be a DOM string, not a HTML collection

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP asks a general question without seemingly having tried to answer it for himself first.

Comment: Well, I'm probably overlooking something. One method I used is looping over each element in the collection and inserting that using insertAdjacentHTML. However I'm wondering if there perhaps is a more elegant way of this.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) expects the second argument to be a DOM string, not an HTML collection, you can simply pass the `stringHTML` to that function:

```js
const stringHTML = `
 <div>
   <h1>This is a div</h1>
   <div>
    <p>inner div</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h2>Another div</h2>
  </div>
`;


/**
 * @param html {String} Representing a single HTML element
 * @return {HTMLCollection} The newly created element
 */

result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stringHTML);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. This would definitely work, however, In the function the input is a HTMLCollection and not a string (text) which the insertAdjecentHTML method expects.